# How to align texts dynamically in Grid tile container in Html in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

This is my parent component.

```
<div class="o-tile-container  ">
                        <div *ngFor="let country of Countrys">
                            <app-country
                                [name]="name"
                                [count]="count"
                                [level]="'Country'"
                            ></app-country>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

This is my common `country` child component Html code

```
<div [matRippleColor]="primary" class="m-tile" matRipple>
    <div class="a-tile-graph">
        <div class="titles">
            <div class="head" id="heading-name">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="sub">{{level}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-tile">
        <div class="o-tile-content">
            <div class="a-tile-title">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="a-tile-count">{{count}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This kind of a thing.

[image]

In here i want to display `heading-name` in the same level of every tile and level `country` in a same level from top in every container. How can i do this?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know it works for you or not. Best wishes . :-)

Comment: ok.I 'l check with it

Comment: Ok. I will be waiting for your feedback. :)

Answer (score 1):

To align text dynamically you can pass your style as `@Input` I have a sample code for you what exactly you want. Please check my code and demo code in stackblitz [Demo LINK StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-ripple-color-h8fpky?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcountry%2Fcountry.component.html)=>

** Parent HTML:**

```
<div class="o-tile-container  ">
                        <div *ngFor="let country of Countrys">
                            <app-country
                                [name]="country.name"
                                [count]="country.count"
                                [level]="country.level"
                                [mystyle]="country.style"
                            ></app-country>
                        </div>
</div>
```

**Child HTML:**

```
 <div style="border-style: solid;width:100px" [matRippleColor]="primary" class="m-tile" matRipple [ngStyle]="this.mystyle">
        <div class="a-tile-graph" >
            <div class="titles">
                <div class="head" id="heading-name"  >{{name}} </div>
                <div class="sub">{{level}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-tile">
            <div class="o-tile-content">
                <div class="a-tile-title">{{name}}</div>
                <div class="a-tile-count">{{count}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**TS:**

**Parent TS:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
 Countrys:any=[];
  rippleColor: string = "white";
  constructor(){
    let c1=new Country();
    c1.count=1;
    c1.level='L1';
    c1.name='A';
    c1.style={'text-align':'center'}
    this.Countrys.push(c1);
    let c2=new Country();
    c2.count=2;
    c2.level='L2';
    c2.name='B';
    c2.style={'text-align':'right'};
    this.Countrys.push(c2);
    let c3=new Country();
    c3.count=3;
    c3.level='L3';
    c3.name='C';
    c3.style={'text-align':'left'};
    this.Countrys.push(c3);
  }
}
class Country{
name;string;
count:number;
level:string;
style:any;
}
```

**Child TS:**

```
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() level:string;
  @Input() name:string;
  @Input() count:number;
  @Input() mystyle:any;
  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```